# React : how to pass and array from inside a Function to the return (JSX)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React (and still new to JS too), and i am trying to build my first React project. I am fetching an API , rendering some items, and building a Search Bar that filters out the items rendered.

My filtering function is more or less working, and inside of it, i store the filtered results in `let result` , but How i should access those results from the return part (JSX area, i think) to loop over them?

This is my code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ListItem from "./ListItem";

const List = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const onInputChange = (event) => {
    setInput(event.target.value);
    const value = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    let result = [];
    result = data.filter((item) =>
      item.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    );
    setInput(result);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/"
      );
      const obj = await response.json();
      setData(obj.results);
    };
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" name={input} onChange={onInputChange}></input>
      {data &&
        data.map((item) => {
          return <ListItem key={item.id} character={item} />;
        })}
    </div>
  );
};
export default List;
```

So far, I can only loop over `input` which contains the `results`, like this `input && input.map((item)`  , but that gives me an empty array when the page is loaded , until i make a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just initialise input as a string so just keep input for keeping input value not result data. You can create another state for keeping result OR put result data back on   Data variable.

Here I am showing you to keep result data separate.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ListItem from "./ListItem";

const List = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState();
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const onInputChange = (event) => {
    setInput(event.target.value);
    const value = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    let result = [];
    result = data.filter((item) =>
      item.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    );
    setSearchResult(result);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/"
      );
      const obj = await response.json();
      setData(obj.results);
    };
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" name={input} onChange={onInputChange}></input>
      {input===""? data &&
        data.map((item) => {
          return <ListItem key={item.id} character={item} />;
        }):
        searchResult &&
        searchResult.map((item) => {
          return <ListItem key={item.id} character={item} />;
        })
        }
    </div>
  );
};
export default List;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This is separating your original data and search result different.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works fine!
Since I would like to have a better understanding...and if you have the time, could you please explain me with a bit more of detail the `input ===""? data && ..." part? 
If you can't, it is ok too.

Comment: We are conditionally rendering the SearchResult and Original Data. If we have any thing in the "input" state, this means we are now in searchResult mode. If there is nothing in "input" mean 'input === ""' this mean we have typed nothing in search input OR clear input, so we need to render all data.

Comment: so, in my words, `if (input = "" ) {show me just Data} or else {show me the searchResults} ` ..kind of, right?

Comment: Exactly.. You got it completely.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a variable to store data after filter:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);  

const onInputChange = (event) => {
  setInput(event.target.value);
};

const result = data.filter((item) =>
  item.name.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase())
);

return (
  ...
  {result?.map((item) => {
    <ListItem key={item.id} character={item} />;
  })}
  ...
)
```

Comment: hey,first of all, thanks! 
But it gives me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`  . ...maybe because input it is empty at the beginning, before any search is made?

Comment: Oh sorry. I updated my answer. You need to declare initial of `data` is []

Comment: oh, yeah! now works like a charm. Thanks a lot!
as i mentioned before, since i am learning, I would like to ask you two things. 1) why should the initial of `data` be [] to work. 
2)why `result?.map...`  and not ` result && result.map...`  
Of course, if you have the time, otherwise, thanks a lot for you great help

Comment: 1- He is initialising data as an Empty Array- It does not matter actually as Javascript is loosely typed.. It will accept values you assign either array or int or string. So it does not matter.
2- result? is doing same thing as you doing result &&. It is new syntax of doing same thing. Actually result? checking wether result exist or Not.

Hope you understand Now

Comment: @VũHuyHoàng your's I am accepting Muhammad's as valid, although your's is still as valid as his, but he was really helpful helping me to understand the whole thing  :)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to filter while rendering,

In this scenario you would only need to save the the input value (onInputChange):

```
const onInputChange = (event) => {
    setInput(event.target.value);
  };
```

Then while rendering you would need to add the filtering logic:

```
  { // if input is not empty
        data
         .filter(item => item.name.includes(input.toLowerCase()))
         .map((item) => {
            return <ListItem key={item.id} character={item} />;
          })
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! that is a different , and very interesting approach. But some reason I still don't see, it is not filtering right. If i type `m` it renders those containing it. but if if i type `mo` displays no items, although some of them contains it.